# Why did the Houston Texans select a defensive player in the 2015 draft?

Tags: nfl, strategy

I have been watching Hard Knocks featuring the Houston Texans.  I watch the NFL draft every year.

It appears to me that the Texans are mainly focusing on defense.  I understand that the defense is great, but it seems to me that they are not focusing enough on offense.

Does anyone know why the Texans drafted a defense player in the first round instead of drafting a QB or a WR? I have been watching NFL network for analysis and have been checking Texans websites and there are no explanations.

Does anybody have any info on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**TLDR**: There was a  cornerback they liked a lot available at pick no. 16, so they picked him

---

The Texans were limited in what they could do in the 2015 draft regarding quarterback, having finished 2014 with a 9-7 record, giving them the 16th pick in the first round. They were one of several teams without a dependable quarterback, but were drafting for instance behind the Buccaneers (1), Titans (2), Redskins (5), Jets (6) and Browns (12), who all could have used a quarterback.

The two highest-rated quarterbacks, Jameis Winston and Marcus Mariota were gone in the first two picks, and trading up into one of the top 2 spots would have been very expensive, if not impossible. No other quarterback was drafted until the third round (Garrett Grayson by the Saints with pick 75) so it would not have crossed their minds to pick any other QB at nr. 16.

But what about other offensive picks? The 20th overall pick Nelson Agholor (Eagles) was still available had they wanted. Obviously the Texans were in the market for a WR, as they picked Jaelen Strong in round 3 and Keith Mumphery in round 5.  Why did they prefer to pick CB Kevin Johnson in round 1? This is a question that only the Texan's GM, coach, and scouts could really answer. The answers they gave the press are full of praise for their first-round pick, but of course we knew that already, as otherwise they wouldn't have taken him.

Anyway, [here are the quotes](http://media.houstontexans.com/article_print.cfm?article_id=1955) of the post first-round media interviews:

**GM Rick Smith**:

> He was by far my favorite corner in the draft. When
>   you talk about just a complete football player in our opinion, this guy is an intelligent guy, he’s
>   smart, he’s tough, he can cover, he’s versatile, he plays on, he plays off, he’s got great
>   instincts, and great play on the ball. In Indy, we really liked him in the room. We thought he
>   was a good man and just enjoyed his career. He’s another guy that has a career there. He’s a
>   three­year starter there.

**Coach Bill O'Brien**

> We’re really happy where it’s at right now. We feel really good about
>   the corner position, specifically after tonight with the addition of
>   Kevin (Johnson). We have two really good veteran corners in Johnathan
>   (Joseph) and Kareem (Jackson) that he can learn behind. He’ll come in
>   and compete right away.

Comment: note: I tried to answer this as best as I could, partly as an experiment to see if it is possible to give a decent objective answer to this kind of "inside the GM's mind" question, with  somewhat flat conclusions. Any downvotes/upvotes/comments will be taken gracefully.